# How to get the bitset back from a file saved as bytearrayoutputstream in java?

Tags: java, filereader, bitset, bytearrayoutputstream

I created a `BitSet` called `b` and saved it to a file using this code snippet in java.

```
    byte[] bs = b.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    baos.write(bs);
    FileOutputStream fr_out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
    baos.writeTo(fr_out);
```

Now can anyone help me figure out how to read this `"output.txt"` file and get back the `BitSet` "b"?

Thanks

Edit in regard to this question being marked as duplicate:
The above given link might have a solution as part of the discussion people had in their comments, but not in the actual answer text-field. Not to mention, the above question does not reference to the question as to how we can get a `BitSet`, it only talks about how to get a `byte` back. Indeed it was altogether another problem that I was facing a day ago, but this question is completely different from that one as I explained above. So I would like to ask the community and the person/s to reconsider their action of marking this question as duplicate with another question of mine itself.

TLDR: This question asked what's 2 + 2 = ?, and the other question asked what's 2 * 2 = ?, but while answering 2 * 2, someone also happened to answer 2 + 2 = ? (it took me hours to find the solution and I did it from another link, not the one posted above), just because answers are similar doesn't mean questions are and above all, I don't want any programmer to keep searching for things for hours when they could just look up this question and find out how to do things, instead of going through the entire web.

Thanks.

Comment: This question **is** a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday. If you thought that **that** question shouldn't be considered a duplicate you should **not** have asked this new question, but edited your previous one.

Comment: Both questions are truly different, so how can I edit that other question when it is perfectly genuine? It just happened that there was another question for `that` question already on stack overflow, but this question was never addressed before, I am the living example as it took 2 hours for me to find a solution to this question. Let me remind you one more time, this question asks about getting BitSet back, not the Byte itself(which was what I asked in my previous question which was already answered on SO, which I agree was a duplicate), hence this in no way is a duplicate.

Comment: So, even after providing a crystal clear explanation, the community still thinks this is a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no answers yet, I would like to post one of the ways that I sorted this out, however it would be great if someone more experienced could give a better solution. Here is what I did to get back my `BitSet` from the file (to which I wrote a `BitSet` using `toByteArray()` method and `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

```
    Path path = Paths.get("output.txt");
    byte[] ans = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    BitSet bits = BitSet.valueOf(ans);
```

Now bits has the original BitSet.